# What is the art style of this picture called?

Tags: style-identification

I want to use AI to transform some of my pictures into this exact style and was hence wondering how this style is called. Thanks for any help/ideas!

[image: tarockcard]
<sub>*[Image from tarot card published by F. Piatnik & Söhne](https://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O595093/tarot-card-f-piatnik/)*</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. The question indicates why you want to know, but it doesn't include any information about what you've researched already. This genre of question is on-topic (although AI currently isn't). Style identification is intended as a tool to help artists understand the theory. It isn't really intended as a service.  It seems like using AI to transform pictures to different styles is something that is becoming popular to experiment with. (cont'd)

Comment: As you might imagine, we don't want the site to become a clearing house for identifying the style of every picture everybody wants to input into AI. It would help if you did a little preliminary research so the question contributes a little more to the discussion. Even if your research isn't fruitful, anything that demonstrates your own investment in getting to an answer will encourage others to write answers.

Comment: To give you a meaningful answer, you either need to provide more images that represent the style you want, or you have to describe the features that are important to you. It's also helpful to know the search terms you used, either the ones that resulted in the correct images or the ones you tried that didn't work. Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: Just noticed, you also need to add attribution for the image (a link to the source). Basically, anything in a post that is not something you created needs attribution. This [link in the Help Section](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) provides some guidance. It focuses on text content, but the same applies to images or any other content.

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.artsy.net/article/artsy-editorial-10-must-see-gallery-la-art-week-2023, https://www.reddit.com/r/tarot/comments/l7zn4x/is_there_a_name_for_the_art_style_used_on_this/, https://tarotx.net/most-50-best-tarot-decks/